# Check that connection is valid

Tags: r, sqldf, rpostgresql

I'm using `RPostgreSQL` and `sqldf` inside my function like this:

```
MyFunction <- function(Connection) {

    options(sqldf.RPostgreSQL.user      = Connection[1], 
            sqldf.RPostgreSQL.password  = Connection[2],
            sqldf.RPostgreSQL.dbname    = Connection[3],
            sqldf.RPostgreSQL.host      = Connection[4], 
            sqldf.RPostgreSQL.port      = Connection[5])

    # ... some sqldf() stuff
}
```

How do I test that connection is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to simply try executing the code, and catching any errors with a nice informative error message. Have a look at the documentation of `tryCatch` to see the details regarding how this works.

The [following blog](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/06/write-cleaner-python-use-exceptions/) post provides an introduction to the exception-based style of programming.

Answer (score 4):

You can check that an existing connection is valid using `isPostgresqlIdCurrent`.

```
conn <- dbConnect("RPgSQL", your_database_details)
isPostgresqlIdCurrent(conn)
```

---

For testing new connections, I don't think that there is a way to know if a connection is valid without trying it.  (How would R know that the database exists and is available until it tries to connect?)

For most analysis purposes, just stopping on an error and fixing the login details is the best approach.  So just call `dbConnect` and don't worry about extra check functions.

If you are creating some kind of application where you need to to handle errors gracefully, a simple `tryCatch` wrapper should do the trick.

```
conn <- tryCatch(conn <- dbConnection(wherever), error = function(e) do_something)
```

Comment: Using `conn <- dbConnect("PostgreSQL", host="localhost",port=5432,dbname='db',user='usr',password='secret')` will return error immediately.

Comment: Oh, I see.  The question was ambiguous.  You want to check the connection before you connect.  I thought that you wanted to check to see if an existing connection was still valid.

Comment: It's better to use the standard generic `dbIsValid()`, which isn't supported in RPostgreSQL, but is supported in RPostgres

Comment: `dbIsValid` seems to check syntax, but not actually attempt the database connection.

Answer (score 4):

My current design uses `tryCatch`:

```r
Connection <- c('usr','secret','db','host','5432')

CheckDatabase <- function(Connection) {

  require(sqldf)
  require(RPostgreSQL)
    
  options(sqldf.RPostgreSQL.user      = Connection[1], 
          sqldf.RPostgreSQL.password  = Connection[2],
          sqldf.RPostgreSQL.dbname    = Connection[3],
          sqldf.RPostgreSQL.host      = Connection[4], 
          sqldf.RPostgreSQL.port      = Connection[5])
    
  out <- tryCatch(
  {
    sqldf("select TRUE;")
  },
  error=function(cond) {
    out <- FALSE
  }
  )    
  return(out)
}

if (!CheckDatabase(Connection)) {
  stop("Not valid PostgreSQL connection.") 
} else {
  message("PostgreSQL connection is valid.")
}
```

Comment: You should use `library()` and not `require()` (so it throws an error if the package is not available), and they should be at the top-level, not inside a function

Comment: or better, `if(!require("pkg", quietly=TRUE)) stop("own error msg")`